# shell script executes in terminal but not with double click on ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu

so i have a shell script on my desktop that executes perfectly when it is run in the terminal:
pullADB.sh

but this collapses the moment i try to double click it.
code:

```
#!/bin/bash

adb pull /sdcard/MovingGratings         ~/Documents/AndroidData/MovingGratings
adb pull /sdcard/LoomingDot             ~/Documents/AndroidData/LoomingDot
adb pull /sdcard/LuminanceCalibrate     ~/Documents/AndroidData/LuminanceCalibrate
adb pull /sdcard/LuminanceContrast      ~/Documents/AndroidData/LuminanceContrast
adb pull /sdcard/MovingDot              ~/Documents/AndroidData/MovingDot  
adb pull /sdcard/MovingGratings         ~/Documents/AndroidData/MovingGratings
adb pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera            ~/Documents/AndroidData/Camera

$SHELL

error: 
/home/XXX/Desktop/pullADB.sh: line 4: adb: command not found

this repeats each time the script tries to call adb.
```

any ideas?

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program `adb` is not found.

Deternime in the terminal where the program is:

```
which adb
```

and then replace the `adb` calls in your script with those values, for exmaple:

```
/usr/bin/adb pull /sdcard/MovingGratings         ~/Documents/AndroidData/MovingGratings
/usr/bin/adb pull /sdcard/LoomingDot             ~/Documents/AndroidData/LoomingDot
...
```

Comment: Thanks! it works now. I only do not understand why it works by running the file within a terminal window, but requires an explicit full path to the adb program with double clicking. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: It's because of the `$PATH` environment variable, where the programs are searched. When you double click the script there are not all paths in this variable, as they are in the terminal.